# Why divide by the square root of the number of p-values when calculating Stouffer's Z?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, standardization, combining-p-values

If Stouffer's method of combining $k$ probabilities is based on the variance of the sum being equal to the sum of the variances, and the variance of $z$ is $1$, why does the Stouffer's formula divide by the square root of $k$ rather than by $k$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to make the variance of the statistic equal to $1$. The statistic, $S$,  is a linear combination of independent $z$-scores:

$$ S = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} Z_{i}}{\sqrt{k}} $$

so the variance of $S$ is

$$ {\rm var}(S) = {\rm var}\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} Z_{i}}{\sqrt{k}} \right) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} {\rm var}( Z_{i}) = \frac{1}{k} \cdot k = 1.$$

If you used $k$ instead of $\sqrt{k}$, you would get a variance of $1/k$.